# Создание вычисляемого поля

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlite, entity-framework

Есть одна таблица (SqlCE), содержащая такие столбцы

```
       [ID]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[Patronymic]
      ,[BirthDay]
      ,[DepartmentID]
```

Нужно добавить еще столбик типа int (вычисляемый), который будет показывать возраст человека на текущий день, путем вычисления его из столбика `[BirthDay]`. Как это можно сделать ? 
Интересует два подхода

1. Сделать это через Sql запрос к этой таблице (если такое возможно)
2. Через Entity Model Конструктор.
3. Получить количество лет простым Sql запросом, который как-то преобразует дату рождения в количество лет

Всем спасибо

Comment: Укажите какую СУБД вы используете

Comment: @MaxU Sql CE 4.0, через стандартный инструмент VS 2015 (SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос к БД:

```
SELECT
   [ID]
  ,[LastName]
  ,[FirstName]
  ,[Patronymic]
  ,[BirthDay]
  ,[DepartmentID] 
  ,DATEDIFF(YEAR, [BirthDay], GETDATE()) AS Age
FROM SqlCE;
```

Это если вы хотите получить данные, например, с помощью `SqlCommand`

В Entity Framework можно добавить вычисляемое поле с атрибутом `NotMapped`, естественно добавлять надо не в генерируемую часть сущности (если вы используете DB First)

```
partial class SqlCE
{
    [NotMapped]
    public int Age 
    {
        get { return (DateTime.Now - Birthday).Days / 365; }
        private set {}
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, подскажите пожалуйста, а куда добавлять нужно этот класс, который с ентитифреймворком ?

Comment: @PolyakovSergey Ну если у вас подход `Code First` то прямо в класс сущности, пометив `NotMapped`. Если подход `DB First`, то при каждой генерации классов из дб исхдники будут переписываться забивая весь ваш код. Но так как, `Entity - partial class`, заводите отдельный исходник в том же пространстве имен пишете `partial class [Ваше имя сущности]` {}  и уже туда добавляете свои вычислимые поля, функции и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить [Computed Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD Age AS datediff(year, BirthDay ,getdate());
```

PS протестировать не могу (не на чем), поэтому не обессудьте если что-то не так ...